# Thunderbird tray icon for mail notifications

Tags: icons, notifications, thunderbird, tray

I was trying to write a script which would add a new mail icon to my system tray, but apparently Thunderbird does not support checking for new mail from the command line.

I've tried a number of plugin, but they all seem to have only a vague description. The ones I tried just modified the *new mail* popup.

Therefore I'm looking for a plugin which displays an icon in the system tray for unread mails. It's not necessary to display the number of unread mails, but it would be nice though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the past I used this plugin: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/firetray/

a quote from the official plugin page:

> display unread messages count in tray icon

Worked perfectly as far as I can remember.

Comment: Firetray does not show mail count in the system tray on KDE due to limitation of `libappindicator`, see [here](https://github.com/foudfou/FireTray/issues/143)

Comment: As of Thunderbird 60.0 (August 6, 2018), FireTray is no longer compatible.

Comment: @Sparhawk Fortunately, there is a fork for Thunderbird 60+ https://github.com/foudfou/FireTray/issues/242

Comment: @tuxayo Brilliant! That works perfectly. Thank you for posting here.